# Page won't expand with content

Tags: html, css

I have had a lot of trouble with my footer and my page content, and am trying to find the correct way to do this. I have my footer at the bottom of the page, but when I add content it overflows the container, please help me.

CSS:

```
#container { 
    width: 75%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:black;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:0.8;

#content { 
    width:100%;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    color: #B05510;
    width: 75%;
    height: 115px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

<body>
<div id='container'>


    <?php
            include 'navfoot/navbar.php'
            ?>
        <div id='content'>
            <div id='paragraph'>
                <p>Eventually our website will be advanced enough for us to have a news feed! But until then we suck!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
            include 'navfoot/footer.php'
            ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not using ID, I  am using the footer tags, I am able to style it.

Comment: Your footer element is positioned absolutely, also I am not sure if you made a typo or not, but `#container` is not closed `}`

Comment: The footer doesn't need an ID if it's used properly `<footer></footer>`. @Crikit can you post the html?

Comment: @Crikit Please post generated html or put it in a http://jsfiddle.net the php code does not help too much. Also it's not clear what you mean by overflows the container

Comment: Here is my website http://sourceblockmc.net/ the issue is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want the footer to act (fixed at bottom always, or relative to the content).  But from what it sounds like, try adding this to your footer CSS:

```
footer {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
}
```

That will keep it fixed and at the bottom of the page (in Chrome, at least).  Otherwise, make the position: relative of the footer and that will sink it to the bottom of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Your container and footer are set to 75% width and your content is set to 100% width. That could be why it's going past the container/footer. It depends on the order. The absolute positioning on the footer could be causing it. You could try changing to relative.

Please post a mock-up of what you are trying to achieve and the HTML to what you have now.

If you are using PHP includes, we need to see what those are. Lots of variables that can cause content to break.

If the issue happens when you are resizing your browser, it's because the paragraph ID (`#paragraph`) has a fixed width of 500px and everything else is percentages.

Fixed on the footer will not resolve the text flowing on top of it.

Comment: Not true... It depends on how the html is structured. What if the content is inside the footer? We should wait for more information.

Comment: @LcSalazar yes I just edited that. I realized if the content was inside the container/footer it would be fine. I did request the HTML.